# What file extention to use for c++ source code

Tags: c++

I wrote some code in notepad but it is written in c++. I've compiled and ran the code online via some available websites and the output is as expected. Now I'd like to save it as a c++ file but not sure what extension to use. I've done some research online and found out that there are so many extensions for c++ (unlike java where the only type I've encountered was .java).

What is the proper file extension to use?

Comment: This is probably going to get opinionated, but I've seen `*.cpp` and `*.cc`.

Comment: Most common is either cpp or cc. It doesn't actually matter. As a reference Google's standard is `cc`, others use `cpp`. Headers are nearly always `h`.

Comment: The nice things about standards is that there are so many of them. gcc, and GNU autotools also recognize `.C` and `.H`.

Comment: I think your question should actually be, "Does my C++ source file extension matter?".  It might fend off close votes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would strongly suggest using .cpp. There are other options, for example .cc, .cxx, but .cpp is by far the most commonly used. Particularly do not use .C (uppercase C), as source file names should never be case-sensitive if you are remotely interested in portability between platforms. For header files, use either .h or .hpp.

Comment: I'm seeing .h extension for headers a lot in my comments as well as online. I only have 1 file and the whole code is written there. What do I put in the .h file?

Comment: @JK Typically, declarations if your project spans more than one .cpp file. If you are writing some trivial "hello world" stuff, you won't need to use header files.

Comment: Yeah it's nothing major just some variable declarations, loops, and if statements so nothing too fancy. I'll just use .cpp. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This is a matter of opinion and convention more than anything else. Boost for example uses `.cpp` for implementation files and `.hpp` for header files, but I've seen `.cc`, `.cxx`, `.c++` and `.C` used in the wild. The latter two are probably a bad idea for portable code however (not all file systems can represent a `+` symbol, and on case-insensitive filesystems `.C` will look like a C file).

The closest thing to "official rules" is probably the C++ Core Guidelines, which [suggest `.cpp` for implementation files and `.h` for header files](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#Rs-file-suffix)

Comment: How does one identify C language header files from C++ header files if `*.h` is used for both?  C compilers get confused when compiling with C++ headers.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I agree, and my preference is to use `.hpp` for that reason. I was just pointing out what the experts who write the guidelines recommend.

Answer (score 2):

`*.cpp` - for code
`*.h` - for header

Comment: I've also seen `.hpp` for C++ headers.

Comment: `.hpp` is good one ))) It is a habit

Comment: I recommend avoiding `*.h` for C++ headers because `*.h` is commonly used for C language headers.  Usually C++ headers should not be mistaken for C language headers (e.g. don't compile C with a C++ header).

Comment: I'm seeing .h extension for headers a lot in my comments as well as online. I only have 1 file and the whole code is written there. What do I put in the .h file?

Comment: @ThomasMatthews: in practice many library headers are polyglots -- they use preprocessor macros to allow inclusion from either language, thus making this distinction moot. Just saying.